# Assigning a specific number of values informed by a probability distribution (in R)

Tags: r, vector, probability

Hello and thanks in advance for the help!

I am trying to generate a vector with a specific number of values that are assigned according to a probability distribution.  For example, I want a vector of length 31, contained 26 zeroes and 5 ones.  (The total sum of the vector should always be five.)  However, the location of the ones is important.  And to identify which values should be one and which should be zero, I have a vector of probabilities (length 31), which looks like this:

```
probs<-c(0.01,0.02,0.01,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.04,0.01,0.01,0.12,0.01,0.02,0.01,
0.14,0.06,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.14,0.01,0.07,0.01,0.01,0.04,0.08,0.01,0.02,0.01)
```

I can select values according to this distribution and get a vector of length 31 using rbinom, but I can't select exactly five values.

```
Inv=rbinom(length(probs),1,probs)
Inv
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Comment: "The total sum of the vector should always be one". Did you mean "...should always be five"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about just using a weighted `sample.int` to select the locations?

```
Inv<-integer(31)
Inv[sample.int(31,5,prob=probs)]<-1
Inv
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: +1 Marvellous, I was mulling using `sample()` whilst reading the Question and @Chase's Answer, but the usage you show escaped me.

Comment: This is definitely quicker, about 20 minutes for a cycle of 1000 sims.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Chase provides a great answer and mentions the problem of the run-away `while()` iteration. One of the problems with a run-away `while()` is that if you do this one trial at a time, and it takes many, say *t*, trials to find one that matches the target number of `1`s, you incur the overhead of *t* calls to the main function, `rbinom()` in this case.

There is a way out, however, because `rbinom()`, like all of these (pseudo)random number generators in R, is vectorised, we can generate *m* trials at a time and check those *m* trials for conformance to the requirements of 5 `1`s. If none are found, we repeatedly draw *m* trials until we find one that does conform. This idea is implemented in the function `foo()` below. The `chunkSize` argument is *m*, the number of trials to draw at a time. I also took the opportunity to allow the function to find more than a single conformal trial; argument `n` controls how many conformal trials to return.

```
foo <- function(probs, target, n = 1, chunkSize = 100) {
    len <- length(probs)
    out <- matrix(ncol = len, nrow = 0) ## return object
    ## draw chunkSize trials
    trial <- matrix(rbinom(len * chunkSize, 1, probs),
                    ncol = len, byrow = TRUE)
    rs <- rowSums(trial)  ## How manys `1`s
    ok <- which(rs == 5L) ## which meet the `target`
    found <- length(ok)   ## how many meet the target
    if(found > 0)         ## if we found some, add them to out
        out <- rbind(out,
                     trial[ok, , drop = FALSE][seq_len(min(n,found)), , 
                                               drop = FALSE])
    ## if we haven't found enough, repeat the whole thing until we do
    while(found < n) {
        trial <- matrix(rbinom(len * chunkSize, 1, probs),
                            ncol = len, byrow = TRUE)
        rs <- rowSums(trial)
        ok <- which(rs == 5L)
        New <- length(ok)
        if(New > 0) {
            found <- found + New
            out <- rbind(out, trial[ok, , drop = FALSE][seq_len(min(n, New)), , 
                                                        drop = FALSE])
        }
    }
    if(n == 1L)           ## comment this, and
        out <- drop(out)  ## this if you don't want dimension dropping
    out
}
```

It works like this:

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo(probs, target = 5)
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
[31] 0
> foo(probs, target = 5, n = 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1
     [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21]
[1,]     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31]
[1,]     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
[2,]     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Note that I drop the empty dimension in the case where `n == 1`. Comment the last `if` code chunk out if you don't want this feature.

You need to balance the size of `chunkSize` with the computational burden of checking that many trials at a time. If the requirement (here 5 `1`s) is very unlikely, then increase `chunkSize` so you incur fewer calls to `rbinom()`. If the requirement is likely, there is little point drawing trials and large `chunkSize` at a time if you only want one or two as you have to evaluate each trial draw.

Comment: +1 although this amount of effort deserves better.  Great answer, thank you.

Comment: I'll echo Andrie's comments. This is a much more scalable solution. I was thinking about the vectorization but couldn't figure out how to take advantage of it here, nice work +1.

Comment: This is fabulous, but I think it will take a little while for me to work through it.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to resample from the binomial distribution with a given set of probabilities until you hit your target value of 5, is that right? If so, then I think this does what you want. A `while` loop can be used to iterate until the condition is met. If you feed very unrealistic probabilites and target values, I guess it could turn into a run-away function, so consider yourself warned :)

```
FOO <- function(probs, target) {
  out <- rbinom(length(probs), 1, probs)

  while (sum(out) != target) {

    out <- rbinom(length(probs), 1, probs)
  }
  return(out)
}
```

FOO(probs, target = 5)

```
> FOO(probs, target = 5)  
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: +1 @Chase, nice Answer and good paint re the `while()` loop. Addressing that problem can be done but makes for a more complex function...

Comment: Thank you!  This works but it takes a long time.  I am running 1000 simulations each with targets 5, 10, 15...etc and it takes about 4 hours for each cycle.  Let me try one of the other methods and get back to you.

Comment: @Laura - both Gavin's and James' answers are a bit more clever than mine, but maybe this simple implementation illustrated how to use the `while` loop concept.

Comment: Indeed!  It is very useful. :)